# Calculate multiple record belong to one ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across a difficult problem that I thought about for a long time without an answer. Thank you very much for your help!

**Question: how can I get all records that belong to customers, over the past 5 years, who bought milk or yogurt AND bought milk, yogurt or apple in the following 15 months? And merge the results by Customer_ID?**

Original data:

| Date | Item | Customer_ID | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Milk | 1345 | 2 |
| 2021-03-01 | Apple | 1345 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | Milk | 8845 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | Milk | 8845 | 2 |
| 2021-11-30 | Cheese | 8845 | 1 |

Target table:

| Customer_ID | Date 1 | Item | Volume | Date 2 | Item | Volume | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1345 | 2021-01-01 | Milk | 2 | 2021-03-01 | Apple | 2 |  |

or simply

| Date | Item | Customer_ID | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Milk | 1345 | 2 |
| 2021-03-01 | Apple | 1345 | 2 |

would be great for step 1 analysis.

My attempts:

```
with t1 as (
   select 
      customer_id
      , date
      , item
      , sum(volume)
   from table
   where item in ('milk', 'yogurt')
     and date between to_date(20181030) and to_date(2023-10-30)
  ),

t2 as (
      select 
      customer_id
      , date
      , item
      , sum(volume)
   from table
   where item in ('milk', 'yogurt','apple')
    and date between to_date(20181030) and to_date(2023-10-30)
  )

select 
   a.customer_id
   , a.date as day1
   , a.item as item1
   , a.volume as v1
   , b.date as day2
   , b.item as item2
   , b.volume as v2
from t1 
    inner join t2 
         on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
            and (t1.date < t2.date and t1.date - t2.date < 456)
```

The result returns a chaotic joint situation. The dates got messed up. There are multiple records for one customer. When the customer bought apple/milk/yogurt multiple times in the next 15 months, the result only returns one record in a line.

Can you please tell me what's wrong and how can I achieve the goal?  Many thanks!

Comment: Did you miss like 20 years in your data? :)

Comment: One thing I did not understand is "in the following 15 months" In your query there is no date limit (from when you are querying) which presumably you are querying from "now" if that is the case how can you have data for something that did not happened?

Comment: oops, thank you for the reminder!! Updated the code to make the dates more realistic.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you for asking! For the "15 months" condition, I only need information about customers who already have multiple purchase records in the past 5 years. If the initial purchase is within 15 months before the end date and the customer doesn't have a follow-up purchase, their record can be ignored.

Comment: Are you sure that's the target table you want? What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: Thanks for asking @drum I think either of the table formats works for me. Table1 is requested and T2 because I want to do some analysis on the purchase frequency/trends

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @drum I'm using Oracle SQL. Is there a special solution in MySQL only?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you are after:

```
CREATE TABLE orig_data (
  purch_date, 
  item,
  cust_id,
  quantity) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           1345,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2021-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Apple',
           1345,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           8845,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           8845,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2023-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Cheese',
           8845,
           1
    FROM   dual);
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orig_data t1,
       orig_data t2
WHERE  UPPER (t1.item) IN ('MILK', 'YOGHURT')
AND    t1.purch_date BETWEEN (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -60)) AND TRUNC (SYSDATE)
AND    t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id
AND    UPPER (t2.item) IN ('MILK', 'YOGHURT', 'APPLE')
AND    t2.purch_date BETWEEN (t1.purch_date + 1) AND ADD_MONTHS (t1.purch_date, 15);
```

Result:

```
PURCH_DATE  ITEM    CUST_ID QUANTITY    PURCH_DATE  ITEM    CUST_ID QUANTITY
2021-01-01  Milk    1345    2           2021-03-01  Apple   1345    2
```

Comment: Thanks! But this only applies when the customer only makes 1 purchase after the initial milk/yogurt purchase right? If a customer made multiple purchases in the 15 months, should I do multiple self-joins to include all record?

Comment: No, you will get another row for each purchase within the 15 months.

Answer (score 0):

To extend my previous answer and answer the question about multiple purchases, here is sample data having 2 purchases within 15 months of the original, plus another than is more than 15 months from the first 2 but less than 15 months from the 3rd:

```
CREATE TABLE orig_data (
  purch_date, 
  item,
  cust_id,
  quantity) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           1345,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2021-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Apple',
           1345,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2022-03-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Yoghurt',
           1345,
           1
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE ('2023-05-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           1345,
           3
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           8845,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Milk',
           8845,
           2
    FROM   dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE ('2023-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           'Cheese',
           8845,
           1
    FROM   dual);
```

Exactly the same query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orig_data t1,
       orig_data t2
WHERE  UPPER (t1.item) IN ('MILK', 'YOGHURT')
AND    t1.purch_date BETWEEN (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -60)) AND TRUNC (SYSDATE)
AND    t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id
AND    UPPER (t2.item) IN ('MILK', 'YOGHURT', 'APPLE')
AND    t2.purch_date BETWEEN (t1.purch_date + 1) AND ADD_MONTHS (t1.purch_date, 15);
```

Results:

```
PURCH_DATE  ITEM    CUST_ID QUANTITY    PURCH_DATE  ITEM    CUST_ID QUANTITY
2021-01-01  Milk    1345    2           2021-03-01  Apple   1345    2
2021-01-01  Milk    1345    2           2022-03-20  Yoghurt 1345    1
2022-03-20  Yoghurt 1345    1           2023-05-07  Milk    1345    3
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get all records that belong to customers, over the past 5 years, who bought milk or yogurt AND bought milk, yogurt or apple in the following 15 months? And merge the results by Customer_ID?

The language is a little confusing. If you want to get:

1. All records for each `customer_id`
2. If, in the past 5 years (60 months), they bought milk or yoghurt
3. And if, in the 15 months after buying the milk or yoghurt, they also bought milk, yoghurt or apple.

Then you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER BY dt
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (^ any_items* milk_yoghurt any_items* milk_yoghurt_apple any_items* $)
  DEFINE
    milk_yoghurt AS  item IN ('Milk', 'Yoghurt')
                 AND dt >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -60),
    milk_yoghurt_apple
                 AS  item IN ('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple')
                 AND dt <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(milk_yoghurt.dt), 15)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  dt          DATE,
  Item        VARCHAR(10),
  Customer_ID INT,
  Volume      INT
);

INSERT INTO table_name (dt, Item,  Customer_ID, Volume)
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 'Milk',   1345, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-03-01', 'Apple',  1345, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 'Milk',   8845, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'Milk',   8845, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-30', 'Cheese', 8845, 1 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | DT | ITEM | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1345 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | Milk | 2 |
| 1345 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | Apple | 2 |

If you want to do it without `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` then you can use analytic functions and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       dt,
       item,
       volume
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         dt,
         item,
         volume,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN dt >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -60)
           AND  item IN ('Milk', 'Yoghurt')
           AND  EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM   table_name x
                  WHERE  x.dt >  t.dt
                  AND    x.dt <= ADD_MONTHS(t.dt, 15)
                  AND    x.customer_id = t.customer_id
                  AND    x.item IN ('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple')
                )
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS num_matches
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  num_matches > 0;
```

Which outputs the same.

---

If you just want the matched items (and not all the items that customer has bought) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER BY dt
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (milk_yoghurt {- any_items* -} milk_yoghurt_apple)
  DEFINE
    milk_yoghurt AS  item IN ('Milk', 'Yoghurt')
                 AND dt >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -60),
    milk_yoghurt_apple
                 AS  item IN ('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple')
                 AND dt <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(milk_yoghurt.dt), 15)
);
```

Which outputs the same for your sample data as that customer has not bought any additional items.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wbfl4lkb)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer after period conditions have been explained. Here is one of the options with a bit bigger sample dataset (added 3 more rows - one with Yoghurt) to test summations and multiple dates.

```sql
WITH
    tbl (   A_DATE, ITEM, CUST_ID,  VOLUME ) AS
        (   Select  To_Date('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Milk', 1345, 2 From Dual Union All
    --  3 rows added
      Select    To_Date('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Milk', 1345, 1 From Dual Union All
      Select    To_Date('2021-03-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Yoghurt', 1345, 7 From Dual Union All
      Select    To_Date('2021-06-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Milk', 1345, 3 From Dual Union All
    --
            Select  To_Date('2021-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Apple', 1345, 2 From Dual Union All 
            Select  To_Date('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Milk', 8845, 2 From Dual Union All
            Select  To_Date('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Milk', 8845, 2 From Dual Union All 
            Select  To_Date('2021-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Cheese', 8845, 1 From Dual
        ),
  t1 AS
      ( Select  Min(A_DATE) "A_DATE",   ITEM, CUST_ID,  Sum(VOLUME) "VOLUME_1"
        From    tbl
        Where   Case When A_DATE Between ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -60) And To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') And ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'Y' OR
                Case When A_DATE Between  A_DATE And ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 15) And ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'Y'
        Group By ITEM, CUST_ID
      ), 
  t2 AS 
      ( Select  Min(A_DATE) "A_DATE",   ITEM, CUST_ID,  Sum(VOLUME) "VOLUME_2"
        From    tbl
        Where   Case When A_DATE Between ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -60) And To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') And ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'Y' OR
                Case When A_DATE Between A_DATE And ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 15) And ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'Y'
        Group By ITEM, CUST_ID
      ),
  t3 AS 
      ( Select  Min(A_DATE) "A_DATE",   ITEM, CUST_ID,  Sum(VOLUME) "VOLUME_3"
        From    tbl
        Where   Case When A_DATE Between ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -60) And To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') And ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'Y' OR
                Case When A_DATE Between A_DATE And ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('2023-10-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 15) And ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'Y'
        Group By ITEM, CUST_ID
      )
```

Main SQL - Option 1 - Result in one row per customer

```sql
SELECT  CUST_ID_1 "CUST_ID", 
        A_DATE_1, ITEM_1, VOLUME_1,
        A_DATE_2, ITEM_2, VOLUME_2,          
        A_DATE_3, ITEM_3, VOLUME_3
        
FROM    ( Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By t1.CUST_ID Order By t1.CUST_ID) "RN", 
                  t1.A_DATE "A_DATE_1", t1.ITEM "ITEM_1", t1.CUST_ID "CUST_ID_1",   t1.VOLUME_1, 
                  t2.A_DATE "A_DATE_2", t2.ITEM "ITEM_2", t2.CUST_ID "CUST_ID_2",   t2.VOLUME_2,
                  t3.A_DATE "A_DATE_3", t3.ITEM "ITEM_3", t3.CUST_ID "CUST_ID_3",   t3.VOLUME_3
          From    t1
          Left Join t2 ON( t2.CUST_ID = t1.CUST_ID And t2.ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple') And t2.A_DATE != t1.A_DATE And t2.ITEM != t1.ITEM)
          Left Join t3 ON( t3.CUST_ID = t1.CUST_ID And t3.ITEM In('Milk', 'Yoghurt', 'Apple') And t3.A_DATE != t1.A_DATE And t3.ITEM != t2.ITEM And t3.ITEM != t1.ITEM)
          Order By t1.CUST_ID, t1.A_DATE
      ) 
WHERE RN = 1 And ITEM_2 Is Not Null
ORDER BY CUST_ID, A_DATE_1
/*
   CUST_ID A_DATE_1  ITEM_1    VOLUME_1 A_DATE_2  ITEM_2    VOLUME_2 A_DATE_3  ITEM_3    VOLUME_3
---------- --------- ------- ---------- --------- ------- ---------- --------- ------- ----------
      1345 01-JAN-21 Milk             6 03-MAR-21 Yoghurt          7 01-MAR-21 Apple            2 */
```

Result for sample data provided:

```sql
/*   
   CUST_ID A_DATE_1  ITEM_1   VOLUME_1 A_DATE_2  ITEM_2   VOLUME_2 A_DATE_3  ITEM_3   VOLUME_3
---------- --------- ------ ---------- --------- ------ ---------- --------- ------ ----------
      1345 01-JAN-21 Milk            2 01-MAR-21 Apple           2     
*/
```

Main SQL - Option 2 - Result in multiple rows

```sql
SELECT  A_DATE, ITEM, CUST_ID, VOLUME
FROM    (   SELECT  A_DATE, ITEM, CUST_ID, VOLUME, Count(Distinct ITEM) OVER(Partition By CUST_ID) "CNT"
            FROM    ( Select  A_DATE,   ITEM, CUST_ID, VOLUME_1 "VOLUME" From t1 Union All
                      Select  A_DATE,   ITEM, CUST_ID, VOLUME_2 From t2 Union All
                      Select  A_DATE,   ITEM, CUST_ID, VOLUME_3 From t3
                    ) 
            GROUP BY A_DATE, ITEM, CUST_ID, VOLUME
        )
WHERE CNT > 1
ORDER BY CUST_ID, A_DATE

/*
A_DATE    ITEM       CUST_ID     VOLUME
--------- ------- ---------- ----------
01-JAN-21 Milk          1345          6
01-MAR-21 Apple         1345          2
03-MAR-21 Yoghurt       1345          7 */
```

Result for sample data provided:

```sql
/*
A_DATE    ITEM      CUST_ID     VOLUME
--------- ------ ---------- ----------
01-JAN-21 Milk         1345          2
01-MAR-21 Apple        1345          2  */
```